# Difference between "commons-io-2.0.jar and commons-io-2.0-sources.jar"

Tags: java

What is the difference between `commons-io-2.0.jar` and `commons-io-2.0-sources.jar`?

When I import commons-io-2.0-sources.jar in Netbeans the `import  org.apache.commns.io.FilenameUtils` is not working. And when `import commons-io-2.0.jar` it works fine. Why?

Comment: One of them contains the, err, sources?

Comment: Look inside and find out? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**commons-io-2.0.jar**

This file contains the classes which you wants to use with your application.
This contains only .class files.

**commons-io-2.0-sources.jar**

This file contains the actual source for that classes.
This contains .java files

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 2):

Reason you get error is, when you have `commons-io-2.0-sources.jar` in your class path is, this jar contains java source and not the class (compiled java files) files.

While `commons-io-2.0.jar` does contains already compiled java source files i.e. class files and hence your code compiles.

Answer (score 1):

`commons-io-2.0.jar` is the actual jar file and `commons-io-2.0-sources.jar` is the source for that jar. This helps to view the source code for debugging purpose.

Comment: Ctrl+Click on any method of that jar will take you to the source code